# path specifications with ffmpge under Windows and python

Tags: python, ffmpeg-python

i have a ffmpge command that should write me textfiles in videos that works fine until the point where i specify path then i get an error message

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0000029cffbedd40] Both text and text file provided. Please provide only one
```

especially here the command is chopped

```
[AVFilterGraph @ 000001287a4eb840] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'textfile=C:UsersRainerDevelopmentpythonfolderVideoCreatersrccontentff4cafdd4d9ed0776cde52c202d11366. txt: fontfile=Anton-Regular.ttf: fontcolor=black: fontsize=40: x=20: y=400: box=1: boxcolor=white@0.8: boxborderw=13:'
```

this is what the python generated command looks like

```
ffmpeg -i basic_video_with_sound.mp4 -vf "drawtext=textfile=C:\Users\Rainer\Development\python\folder\VideoCreater\src\content\ff4cafdd4d9ed0776cde52c202d11366. txt: fontfile=Anton-Regular.ttf: fontcolor=black: fontsize=40: x=20: y=400: box=1: boxcolor=white@0.8: boxborderw=13:" youtube_shorts_ff4cafdd4d9ed0776cde52c202d11366.mp4
```

i've tried masking the path quite a bit, but even when the path matches like in the example, i get the error message shown

does anyone have an idea how the path is specified? Maybe it is helpful to know that python gets a variable passed to it and that the command is created from a format string. It should be noted that it is no problem to specify a variable in the output file. Only just the specification of the textfile makes problems.

I have already tried to mask the paht specification. It was tried to write the path information directly into the command without variable

Comment: Two basic things to try: Double up your backslashes; or change them to forward slashes.